# Local banner notification for terminating App

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I want to show banner notification when user quits the Application. And on tapping that banner I want my Application to open.

```
func showBanner() {

    UIApplication.shared.cancelAllLocalNotifications()

    let notif = UILocalNotification.init()
    notif.alertBody = "Your Message Here..."
    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

    UIApplication.shared.presentLocalNotificationNow(notif)
}
```

If I put this code in `applicationDidEnterBackground` it works fine; But, when I put it in `applicationWillTerminate`, it doesn't.

Any workaround?

**EDIT:**

Added `fireDate` like following:

```
var dc = DateComponents()
dc.second = 2 // 2 seconds from current date time
notif.fireDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dc, to: Date())
```

Still not working. Any idea?

Comment: where you called this `showBanner`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik It works when I put it withing `applicationDidEnterBackground` But, it doesn't work when I put it within `applicationWillTerminate` as mentioned in queston.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806293/what-is-the-delegate-method-that-will-called-when-closing-an-iphone-app-by-press

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik The link you provided says `applicationWillTerminate`. But, it's not working. That's what the question is.

Comment: @sweta.me if you get any useful answer or assign  guarantee that **applicationWillTerminate** will be executed . please share thanks

Comment: @NazmulHasan Posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same code works when I set in **App communicates using CoreBluetooth** in `info.plist` for `Requires Background Modes`.

Got the hint from [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988245/local-notification-on-application-termination/21714121#21714121)

Let's hope, Apple does not reject my App.

Answer (score 0):

no guarantee that `applicationWillTerminate` will ever get called may that is the reasone your code not working  . so if your need to do anything before app exist then call `applicationDidEnterBackground`

more check this [iOS - How to guarantee that applicationWillTerminate will be executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39920541/ios-how-to-guarantee-that-applicationwillterminate-will-be-executed)

Comment: But, I want the notification to appear only when the application is terminated. Not when it's in background. Any workaround?

Comment: How would I know? I don't even have that much reps to downvote. :D Btw, you can post the answer as comment to question, as it is not actually an answer.