# Send notification to App when Application is quit

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilocalnotification, remote-notifications

I want to show a notification (local OR remote) when Application is terminated or killed from background.

There is an App on AppStore which does the same thing. But, I don't know I can provide link to that App here or not.

I tried creating a local notification and setting up it in:

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {

}
```

But, this function does not get called, as mentioned in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260410/how-to-perform-last-actions-upon-user-exiting-an-iphone-app/) & [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32223037/how-to-execute-code-when-my-app-terminated-in-background-in-ios) links.

Is there any way I can accomplish this? Can I provide reference App link here?

---

**Edit**

This question if flagged as duplicate of the of some other question which doesn't solve my issue.

[Reference App](http://app.appsflyer.com/id578830929?pid=website&c=homepage_hero) -- This is what I am trying to achieve. Kill the app from background and you will get the notification.

Comment: Does your app support background execution?...

Comment: @sanman Yes, it does.

Comment: Thats why the method is not working for you.The docs says "For apps that do not support background execution or are linked against iOS 3.x or earlier, this method is always called when the user quits the app."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local notification on application termination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988245/local-notification-on-application-termination)

Comment: You may find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/39921446/6285303

Comment: @mrabins That possible duplicate says it's not possible. Where as I can provide you the reference application where it's happening flawlessly.

Comment: Did you see this? https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/517/